# How can I navigate to a specific composable when sending a notification

Tags: android, kotlin, notifications, android-notifications, composable

I want to know how can I send the user to a specific composable when they click in a notification.

My code is this, I know it have to be in the Intent and PendingIntent but I don't know how, I search and they talk about sending to another Activity but I want the same Activity but diferent Composable.

```
fun FirNotification() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        notificationChannel = NotificationChannel(channelID, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)
    }
    val intent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)

    notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelID)
    notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
    notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
    //notificationBuilder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, "OPEN", pendingIntent)
    notificationBuilder.setContentTitle(title)
    notificationBuilder.setContentText(msg)
    notificationBuilder.setOngoing(false)
    notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true)
    notificationManager.notify(100, notificationBuilder.build())
}
```

I want to send to a different composable not the main one.

Comment: Are you using Navigation Compose? The docs talk explicitly about [deep linking to a particular composable](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#deeplinks).

Comment: I dont like that solution.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this for hours, but found solution. So basically, deep link is the answer, as stated in this link [https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#deeplinks][1]

So what I have done is:

1. Create Pending intent with desired deepLink that will be converted to uri.

   ```
   private fun createPendingIntent(deepLink: String): PendingIntent {
       val startActivityIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, deepLink.toUri(), 
           this,MainActivity::class.java)

       val resultPendingIntent: PendingIntent? = TaskStackBuilder.create(this).run {
           addNextIntentWithParentStack(startActivityIntent)
           getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
       }
       return resultPendingIntent!!
   }
   ```
2. Then add deep link parameter to composable inside NavHost. The example of uri pattern `"https://example.com/settings"`

   ```
   composable(<Composable_Route>,
       deepLinks = listOf(navDeepLink { uriPattern = <Your_URI_PATTERN> })
   ){
       val viewModel = hiltViewModel<SettingsScreenViewModel>()
       SettingsScreen(navController = navController, viewModel = viewModel)
   }
   ```
3. Also the same uri must be added to `Manifest.xml` as intent filter. This is needed so the app can know when uri from pending intent is used.

   ```
   <intent-filter>
       <data android:scheme="https" android:host="example.com/settings" />
   </intent-filter>
   ```

In my case real https url is not needed so it works with similar example.
But, I face another problem where when I enter composable from intent, a go back (with android back button), it will return where it needs to return, but if you try to go back again from that previous composable(in my case that is top on backStackEntry), it will not exit the app, but launch it again from start of whole NavigationGraph. If anyone had similar issues, please share with us.
I hope my answer will help someone as Jetpack is still new in some things and documentation is not very well explained.

Answer (score -1):

I solve it using a putextra:

```
  val intent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java).putExtra("screen",screen)
```

and then reading it:

```
val screen: String? = intent.getStringExtra("screen")
if(screen != null) {
                navController.navigate(screen)
            }
```

Comment: This solution isn't actually going to work - every time you go through a configuration change (like rotating your device) or through process death and recreation, you're going to add another copy of this destination onto the back stack on top of whatever is being restored.

Comment: Is better than using deep linking

Comment: suggest me a example of deeplink for jetpack compose